# How to get all text from all textboxes with class txt_Answer

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    <table id="tb_Answers">
    <tbody>
   <td>
    <input class="txt_Answer" placeholder="Enter Answer">
    </td>
    <td>

    <td colspan="4">
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <input class="txt_Answer" placeholder="Enter Answer">
    </td>
    <td>
    <td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <input class="txt_Answer" placeholder="Enter Answer">
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

I got 3 inputs with answers.How to get all this text/answer by class txt_Answer i tried  this

```
$('*[class="txt_Answer"]').val()
```

but this returns me only the first value not all of thaem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By iterating and creating an array with $.map :

```
var values = $.map($('input.txt_Answer'), function(el) {return el.value;});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/CFUmY/1/)

You should also validate your HTML, as it's not valid

Answer (score 0):

Try this code which is using the [each method](http://api.jquery.com/each/) :

```
$('.txt_Answer').each(function() {
    text = $(this).val()
    alert(text)
})
```

Comment: Each is not useful for this task. Usually you want the values, not doing stuff to the values of the input fields.